# Is there any way to select all input elements of a form including those outside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is there an 'official' way to get all input elements of a form **including those outside of the form** that use the new HTML5 'form' attribute for input elements, or do I have to make a union of some custom selectors? By official i mean standard idiom or jQuery provided. Thanks.

EDIT: See this example http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form

EDIT2: I ended up doing this: $("#formId :input, :input[form='formId']")

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Do you want only `<input>` elements, or all the types which are selected by `':input'` (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and `<button>`)?

Comment: @Vidas all of them: Whatever would be used by the browser to gather the parameters to send to the server on a submit of the form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

The `form.elements` collection holds all form controls - both those who are within the form, and those who are associated with it via the `form` attribute.

So, just get the reference to the form, and retrieve the `.elements` property:

```
var form = document.getElementById( 'form1' );
var allFormControls = form.elements;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bsFcf/

If you want to place all form controls inside a jQuery object, I recommend this:

```
$( $( '#form1' )[0].elements )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bsFcf/1/

Comment: Due to the fact, that the form attribute also can be used on fieldset elements and a form can also contain input elements pointing to another form, this answer is right. You can additionally filter for inputs: $( $('#form-id').prop('elements') ).filter(':input');

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Ah yes, I didn't notice that only INPUT elements are wanted. So yes, `.filter( ':input' )` should be appended...

Comment: This will select also all `button` elements inside your form (eg. submit button).

Answer (score 4):

You can combine a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and a [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
var $inputs = $("form :input, :input[form]");
```

Comment: With a minor adjustment it is what brad also suggested. I ll accept this just based on the time of the answer.

Comment: I have to take back the accept in favor of the answer Sime gave.

Answer (score 2):

In case you were referring to the new `form="myform"` attribute you can now add to elements, and want to select elements based on that, [you can do the following](http://jsfiddle.net/UdnUf/):

```
$('[form="myform"]');
```

Using the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: More or less. I want that + the elements that are physically contained in that form but dont have the new attribute set. Essentially I want all the elements that 'submit' would include to send to the server. I guess I will have to union your selector with one that selects the physically contained. I have edited my question to include an example that exactly describes the situation

Comment: Cant make it work.. email doesnt show up, but I understand that u are joining the 2 selectors. I was wondering if there is something simple like a simple selector. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $my_input_fields = $(":input");
```