# Is it possible to disable all the inputs from a page with VueJS and BootstrapVue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have multiple buttons and form inputs in one page. All these buttons and form inputs need to be disabled or enabled depending on a condition.

I know that it is possible to use the disabled keyword inside a tag to disable a specific input or button. Also, I can just add the code

```
:disabled="true"
```

to disable the inputs depending of the boolean value of a variable.
However, this solution is not acceptable for me, since I will have to add this line of code to every inputs on my page (I may create new pages in the future, containing as many inputs).

I would like to know if there's a way that allows me to simply disable the parent container of all the inputs so that the children item (the inputs)  are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the Vue instance itself of the VM when running your code you can have something like this when you console.log(this),

It will give you output similar to this if you use the correct scope:

```
{
$attrs
$options
.......
$el
}
```

Inside $el there's object properties for accessing firsElementChild, previousElementChild, previousElementSibling, etc. There's a lot of HTML related properties, however, accessing HTML element this way can get messy pretty fast. I think that your best solution is the one you already mentioned or changing the CSS class dynamically.

If you use v-if to conditional render on a parent you can achieve pretty similar functionality too.

[See: Conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)

Comment: IMHO this seems overly complicated when you could just do standard targeting, in plain Javascript, for any `input` element in the webpage (Vue or not) then perform an action (disabled or enable). This has been answered many times in other SO questions, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535084/is-there-any-way-to-select-all-input-elements-of-a-form-including-those-outside. Vue wouldn't provide much power here except the convenience of using Vue's `$refs` for targeting.